# Events in junit with Mockito

Tags: events, junit, java-ee-6, mockito

I try to test javax.enterprise.event.Event mocked by mockito but the following exception is thrown

```
Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/enterprise/util/TypeLiteral
```

The class looks like

```
public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock Event<MyAlarm> event;
    //...
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //...
    }
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.event = event;
        //...
        verify(event, never()).fire(any(MyAlarm.class));
        //...
    }
}
```

I add following to the pom.xml (maven project)

```
    <repository>
        <id>glassfish</id>
        <name>GlassFish Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish</url>
    </repository>
```

and include the glassfish-embedded-all in front of the javax (javaee-web-api) dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

What I have done wrong or what do I misunderstand?

Comment: when I remove the second dependency I can't build my project. All Java EE functions (javax.*) are not recognized any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some slight mistakes. This article [Unit Testing for Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/unittesting-455385.html)
 by Adam Bien pointed me in the right direction.
I removed the javaee-web-api dependency and add the glassfish-embedded-all dependency. My `pom.xml` looks like:

```
    <!-- .... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- .... -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>java.net</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This works well for me and I can test java ee events (or mock-it out).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround what I did was to add an inner class marked `@Singleton` in my test class that acts as an event observer. Such a class would look like this:

```
@Singleton
public static class MyEventObserver {
    MyEvent event;

    public void onMyEvent(@Observes MyEvent event) {
            this.event = event;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my test class I inject this class:

```
@Inject MyEventObserver observer;
```

and finally in the test method I would do something like:

```
Assert.assertNotNull(observer.event);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The methods in `TypeLiteral` are final (see [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/util/TypeLiteral.html)) which means that Mockito can not mock them (see the [Mockito FAQ](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html)).

Perhaps consider using [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) (it can work in conjunction with Mockito I think) which apparently can mock final methods

Comment: So, it is not possible to mock `javax.enterprise.event.Event` in a Class with Mockito?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  A mock works by providing dummy implementations of the methods, but it can't do that if those methods are specified as final.